# How do I update npm packages in Expo

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

In my regular React Native projects, I run `npm update {package-name}` regularly to make sure my libraries are up-to-date. For example, I use a third party user authentication package and want to make sure that I use the latest stable version.

What is the Expo equivalent of `npm update`?

I understand using `expo install {package-name}` has an advantage over `npm i {package-name}` in that it makes sure the installed version of the package will be compatible with Expo SDK the app is using. That's why I'm reluctant to run `npm update {package-name}` and want to put Expo in the equation.

How do I update my npm packages in my Expo app?

Comment: Check out this https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8563#issuecomment-636526864. might help what you want

Comment: @VinaySingh Downgrading seems not to happen in my case, [I opened a case for that](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/discussions/4528) to find out how this can be done properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

expo only updates the third packages with the core update of expo sdk, so you have to wait to ensure the compatibily.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear but thank you for the answer!

Comment: It will not update packages you added yourself, thus this answer does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Run expo upgrade
according to your expo sdk,
here is the last one so far
follow https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-45-f4e332954a68

Comment: But this will only upgrade the packages added by expo itself, not all packages in the package.json.

Comment: I believe you can try to manually update a version of the package and see if it is still compatible with Expo. I could not make it work to update everything at once

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not satisfying, but [there is actually a way](https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-to-downgrade-all-npm-packages-to-compatible-versions-after-upgrading-all-dependencies/65939) which is to call `expo-cli doctor --fix-dependencies` after upgrading all packages by running [`npm-check-updates -u`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates).